# Syntax error in conditional expression in shell script

Tags: shell

I write a shell script. I have a problem that I want to determine folder name manually. Actually, I solved with @Suhas's helping. When I execute my script, I have an error

```
./scriptname: line 5: syntax error in conditional expression
./scriptname: line 5: syntax error near `"${folder2}"'
./scriptname: line 5: `    if [[ ! -d "${folder1}" "${folder2}" ]]; then'
```

Can someone figure out what's wrong?

Comment: Check them separately.

Comment: They can not separate. Because I need "-d folder1 folder2". Not "-d folder1" or "-d folder2"

Comment: `&&` / logical `AND` seems to be what you want...

Comment: BTW, I rolled back the edit, as the question on its own after your edit would have to little information to go one, and the answer won't make sense without them. You could trim it down if you like, but please keep the information of the original in there for the ones finding this question & the answers later.

Comment: _"./scriptname: line 5: syntax error in conditional expression"_  Yes, it abundantly clear. You're missing a closing quote `"`. That would also be a syntax error.

Comment: Now, it seems good, isn't it?

Comment: Well, let me at least show the food peope the _actual error_ you seem eager to hide. Keep in mind, this page is not only for _you_ to get the answer to _your_ question, but also for other struggling with a similar question to _find_ your question and the answers, so he/she doesn't need to ask the same question again.

Comment: Yes, but you deleted _even that part_ (so _I_ had to put it back in again).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Giving a parameter and help section to shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366083/giving-a-parameter-and-help-section-to-shell-script)

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
if [[ ! -d "${folder1}" "${folder2}" ]]; then
```

needs to be separated into 2:

```
if [ ! -d "${folder1}" ] && [ ! -d "${folder2}" ]; then
```

Comment: @user2874061: No, you don't. Whatever syntax your `./scriptname` accepts for its command-line arguments, the shell's built-in `[[ ! -d blah ]]` only accepts one argument. Just what do you expect `[[ ! -d "${folder1}" "${folder2}" ]]` to do?

Comment: @user2874061 Unfortunately, that's not how `-d` works in bash. You can run the script any way that you want but in order to test if 2 directories exist or not, you need to test them **separately**.

Comment: @sputnick Also no need to use `[[` instead of `[`.  `[` is more portable, `[[` has more intuitive semantics in many cases (but in this case has no noticeable advantage).

Comment: `[[` when already using bash is the way to go. It's more powerful.

Answer (score 1):

A better & valid solution for a double test still using `[[ ]]` bash test :

```
if [[ ! -d "${folder1}" && ! -d "${folder2}" ]]; then
```

### Note

`[[` is a bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals. Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, we(wooledge.org) recommend `[[`.

Comment: Hm, what are the advantages of `[[ test && test ]]` over `[ test ] && [ test ]`? I'm genuinely curious about what makes it better (don't know that much about bash internals).

Comment: `[[ -d "$folder1" && -d "folder2" ]]`

Comment: Added explanations in my original POST.